# SQL Server @@error not working. Doesn't go into "if"

Tags: sql, sql-server, error-handling, raiserror

I wrote a very simple procedure. I am deliberately making a mistake in the procedure. but the error is not working. I want to return the error I want with raiserror. but it doesn't even go inside the "if".

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dene
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO bddksektor ([tcmbkodu], [aktif], [bddksektorkodu]) 
    VALUES ('a', 1, 1)

    -- I knowingly made a mistake. normally the 1st parameter is int.
    -- I'm entering varchar so that it can enter "if" and return an error. but it doesn't

    IF @@ERROR <> 0
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Hata', 16, 1, 61106)
        RETURN 61106
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            [tcmbkodu], [aktif], [bddksektorkodu]
        FROM 
            [dbfactoringtest].[dbo].[bddksektor]
        ORDER BY
            tcmbkodu ASC
    END

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

SQL Server returns its own error when I run the procedure. It does not return the error I wrote because it does not enter the "if"

Error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure dene, Line 11 [Batch Start Line 1]
> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'a' to data type int

Comment: Why not using `TRY...CATCH`? The `IF` won't be entered if the `INSERT` fails, as the batch will already be aborted. I also recommend switching the `THROW` (as the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) recommends you to too).

Answer (score 1):

As I mention in the comment, use a `TRY...CATCH`. For your SQL if the first `INSERT` fails the batch will be aborted, and so the `IF` won't be entered, because it won't be reached. I also recommend switching to `THROW` instead of `RAISERROR` as noted in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> **Note**
> The RAISERROR statement does not honor SET XACT_ABORT. New applications should use THROW instead of RAISERROR.

This gives you something like this:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.dene AS --Always schema qualify
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO dbo.bddksektor ([tcmbkodu],[aktif],[bddksektorkodu]) --Always schema qualify
        VALUES ('a',1,1);

        SELECT [tcmbkodu]
              ,[aktif]
              ,[bddksektorkodu]
        FROM [dbfactoringtest].[dbo].[bddksektor] --Why is this using 3 part naming? Is this copy of bddksektor in a different database?
        ORDER BY tcmbkodu ASC;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        THROW 61106, N'Hata', 16;
        RETURN 61106;
    END CATCH;

    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END
```

Comment: I've already done it with "try-catch". but I want to do it using "if". but you say it is not done with "if".  is it correct?

Comment: `BEGIN...TRY` is the way to go, @batuhan343434 . Why don't you want to use it..?

Comment: I will use multiple "if" conditions when the procedure becomes much larger. According to the data from the variable, it will go inside the "if". A programmer I saw did this using "@@error" and "if". but it didn't work for me. I'm trying to make it like him

Comment: Why following someone else's bad habits... Just because you saw someone else using a hammer to put a screw into a wall doesn't mean you should, @batuhan343434 .

Comment: You can use multiple `TRY ... CATCH` blocks. They work in a similar way to an `IF @@error`.